# How to use recycler view in xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am using [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/) link for making recycler view in xamarin.

**My Steps are:**

1. Add Support library through Solution explorer->Reference->Right Click on Reference->Manage NuGet Package then add Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView and Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.
2. After adding libaray

In mainactivity.axml added

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
         android:scrollbars="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

But I got the following errors:

[image]

Comment: Check whether your C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin contains Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView folders & its version folder is not empty.

Comment: Yes @sJy its version folder is empty.

Comment: So your build process was interupted someway. Build process will take some time to download zip files required for these.

Comment: @sJy Okay so what can I do now?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version folder inside Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView is empty, which should have caused due to interruption in build process.

Any newly added Nuget Packages will require those to be downloaded as zip to **zips** folder & unzipped to respective reference folders at `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin\`.

Try

- Remove your Nuget reference from solution
- Delete all zip files from `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips` folder
- Add Nuget references again
- Build & wait for it to complete.(If build was successfull, the version folder for the `RecyclerView` libary won't be empty)

> Note : Ensure you have a reliable network connection :-)